# Emulating Xbox 360 controller using xboxdrv not working for Dualshock controller on 14.04

Tags: games, steam, emulation, gamepad

I had been happily using my PS3 controller emulated to an xbox 360 controller on my Ubuntu 13.10 and lower Steam library.

I recently updated to 14.04, and now `xboxdrv` just does not work anymore.

This is what I do:

- Plug in DS3 into USB port
- Click the Playstation button on it
- It shows all 4 leds lighting at the same time slowly
- `sudo xboxdrv --detach-kernel-driver`

This is the output:

```
Controller:        PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller
Vendor/Product:    054c:0268
USB Path:          003:004
Controller Type:   Playstation 3 USB

Your Xbox/Xbox360 controller should now be available as:
  /dev/input/js4
  /dev/input/event15
```

And then the Player 1 LED lights up.

**BUT** after about 3 seconds, the 4 LEDs start lighting slowly again and the controller does not seem to do anything. I use `jstest-gtk` to see if input is being registered correctly but nothing happens when I click any of the buttons.

As I said, I had been using this method up until 14.04, and it was working flawlessly. Has anyone been able to get `xboxdrv` to work with a Dualshock 3 controller on 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was. Recently, [this Ubuntu Launchpad bug report came to light](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1326725). It states that the kernel regressed from `.24` to `.25`.

What I did then was go to the mainline kernel builds of Ubuntu and installed `3.13.11` as that's what the bug report stated as a fix:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11-trusty/

You download the `all` package, `headers` package and the `image` package of the type "generic". Choose the correct packages for your OS (32/64 bit).

Once you download those 3 packages, go to the folder and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

And it will install the new kernel. Finally reboot it and it should be default in your GRUB config.

If you really can't figure it out, [I used this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) to do the upgrade.